# Docs about comparison operators saying case-sensitive

Tags: apex, operators

<sub>Above all sorry about the title, couldn't find a *good* one. Please edit if you think of any</sub>

I stumbled upon this description about equals operator in [Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_security_datasets_predicate_operatorscomparison.htm&type=5).

```
OPERATOR    NAME    DESCRIPTION
  ==       Equals   ... String comparisons that use the equals operator are case-sensitive
```

But in Developer Console I get the result as below.

```
'foo' == 'Foo' 
>>> True
```

My question is, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That documentation is about Einstein Analytics, which has different semantics from other areas of Salesforce.

In [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm), the `==` operator is case-insensitive:

> String comparison using == is case-insensitive.

Case-sensitive String comparison in Apex is done using `String.equals()`. Note also there's a few places where Apex does do case-sensitive String matching; `List.contains()` and `Set.contains()` are among them.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. The documentation is not about Apex.

Comment: A-ha! That's why.! Brain-fart hits hard at 5pm of Friday. Thanks. Will accept whenever timer lets me.